# Firebase RealTime Database relation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm still trying to learn about this NoSQL database and its integration with Android.

I had a SQL database before and it has some relations between tables, like this

### User

int id
text name
int groupId

### Group

int id
text name

In Firebase I implement them like this,

```
{
    "user": {   
        "1": {   
            "name": "Jon",   
            "groups": {   
                "group1": true   
            }   
        }   
    },   
    "groups": {   
       "group1": {   
           "name": "Group 1"   
       }
    }
}
```

Till here I think its fine, but when I write some code in Java I don't know how to put my POJO.
Here is what I've done till now:

```
public class Group {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class User {

    private String name;
    private Group groups;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Group getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Group groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }
}
```

And now reading the values. (Is on method OnCreate)

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        DataSnapshot next = children.iterator().next();
        User value =  next.getValue(User.class);
        Group group = value.getGroups();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
             // Failed to read value
    }
});
```

But my group's value is always null. What am I doing wrong?? How do I relate user with groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main problem that I found is your `Group` object in the `User` class:**
In fact, it should not be a custom object at all, if it stays in the current structure, but a `Map`. [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) is the map object - a collection which has a `key`, and a `value`, just like a child in the `Realtime Database`.

If a `group` name (=key) didn't have a `true` (=value) next to it - the names could have been stored in `String` variables, but this is not the case, because every child in the `Realtime Database` must have a value, and storing a "dummy" value next to a group name makes each group a part of a `Map`. This current "dummy" is a `boolean`, and that's why this will be the groups' data type:`Map<String, Boolean> groups`.

Therefore, your `User` class should be as follows:

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private Map<String,Boolean> groups;
```

A good example of using this exact type would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475470/nested-lists-in-firebase).